# Decrypt and encrypt between clients and server by ssl

Tags: ssl, encryption, cryptography, ldap

Deploying ldap server with SSL. After some study, I find out that if I want the ldap server and clients to encrypt and decrypt the data, the ldap server need to hold all of the public keys generated by different clients.

[verify without clients](http://s4.postimg.org/g7hgzzatp/without_Verify_Client.png)

[verify clients](http://s1.postimg.org/e3syvr03z/verify_Client.png)

These two graphs illustrate my idea(not sure this idea can work or not).It could be a mess if the server need to hold the public keys generated by different clients.Is this the standard solution to encrypt and decrypt within ldap server and clients?If no, which one is the standard solution?

Do I have an easier way to encrypt and decrypt the data between ldap server and clients, without asking the ldap server to hold every public keys generated by the clients?

Comment: Your question is not related to programming, but to general security knowledge. http://Security.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if I want the ldap server and clients to encrypt and decrypt the data, the ldap server need to hold all of the public keys generated by different clients.

Wrong. The LDAP server needs the *certificates* of the clients only (a) if it is using client authentication and (b) if they are self-signed.

SSL does not use public-private key encryption. It uses symmetric encryption via a negotiated session key, that has nothing to do with client keys whatsoever.